# Programming in Objective-C Stephen Kochan. Chapter 21, exercise 21.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

***Hello!***

I have a trouble in 21.2 exercise. In that exercise I build Fraction calculator. I have 9 buttons and math actions. When I press any digit (either 1,2,3 or any else) on iOS Simulator it generates an error:

```
    2012-08-05 15:09:05.026 Fraction_Calculator[834:f803] -[ViewController digit5]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6843e00
2012-08-05 15:09:05.029 Fraction_Calculator[834:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController digit5]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6843e00'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x14b5022 0xeb5cd6 0x14b6cbd 0x141bed0 0x141bcb2 0x14b6e99 0x1b14e 0x1b0e6 0xc1ade 0xc1fa7 0xc1266 0x403c0 0x405e6 0x26dc4 0x1a634 0x139fef5 0x1489195 0x13edff2 0x13ec8da 0x13ebd84 0x13ebc9b 0x139e7d8 0x139e88a 0x18626 0x28ad 0x2815)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

*What that means:* "**unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6843e00**" and "**'-[ViewController digit5]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6843e00'**".

*Here is my code of that program:*

**ViewController.h**

**Code: Objective-C**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Calculator.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *display;

-(void) processDigit: (int) digit;
-(void) processOp: (char) theOp;
-(void) storeFracPart;

-(IBAction) clickDigit: (UIButton *) sender;

-(IBAction) clickPlus;
-(IBAction) clickMinus;
-(IBAction) clickMultiply;
-(IBAction) clickDivide;

-(IBAction) clickOver;
-(IBAction) clickEquals;
-(IBAction) clickClear;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

**Code: Objective-C**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    char                op;
    int                 currentNumber;
    BOOL                firstOperand, isNumerator;
    Calculator          *myCalculator;
    NSMutableString     *displayString;
}

@synthesize display;

-(void) processDigit:(int)digit
{
    currentNumber=currentNumber*10+digit;

    [displayString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", digit]];
    display.text=displayString;
}

-(IBAction) clickDigit:(UIButton *)sender
{
    int digit=sender.tag;

    [self processDigit: digit];
}

-(void) processOp: (char) theOp
{
    NSString *opStr;

    op=theOp;

    switch(theOp)
    {
            case '+':
                opStr=@"+";
                break;
            case '-':
                opStr=@"-";
                break;
            case '*':
                opStr=@"*";
                break;
            case '/':
                opStr=@"/";
                break;
    }

    [self storeFracPart];
    firstOperand=NO;
    isNumerator=YES;

    [displayString appendString: opStr];
    display.text=displayString;
}

-(void) storeFracPart
{
    if(firstOperand)
    {
       if(isNumerator)
       {
           myCalculator.operand1.numerator=currentNumber;
           myCalculator.operand1.denominator=1;
       }
        else
            myCalculator.operand1.denominator=currentNumber;
    }
    else if (isNumerator)
    {
        myCalculator.operand2.numerator=currentNumber;
        myCalculator.operand2.denominator=1;
    }
    else
    {
        myCalculator.operand2.denominator=currentNumber;
        firstOperand=YES;
    }
currentNumber=0;
}

-(IBAction) clickOver
{
    [self storeFracPart];
    isNumerator=NO;
    [displayString appendString: @"/"];
    display.text=displayString;
}

-(IBAction) clickPlus
{
    [self processOp: '+'];
}

-(IBAction) clickMinus
{
    [self processOp: '-'];
}

-(IBAction) clickMultiply
{
    [self processOp: '*'];
}

-(IBAction) clickDivide
{
    [self processOp: '/'];
}

-(IBAction) clickEquals
{
    if (firstOperand==NO)
    {
        [self storeFracPart];
        [myCalculator performOperation: op];

        [displayString appendString: @"="];
        [displayString appendString: [myCalculator.accumulator convertToString]];
        display.text=displayString;

        currentNumber=0;
        isNumerator=YES;
        firstOperand=YES;
        [displayString setString: @""];        
    }
}

-(IBAction) clickClear
{
    isNumerator=YES;
    firstOperand=YES;
    currentNumber=0;
    [myCalculator clear];

    [displayString setString:@""];
    display.text=displayString;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //[super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    firstOperand=YES;
    isNumerator=YES;
    displayString=[NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:40];
    myCalculator=[[Calculator alloc]init];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

**Thanks a lot!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be happening if you haven't set the tag value for each button. For example, for button 4 the tag should be 4 and so on:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I read in the book that I have to set the tags for buttons, but I can't find where in Inspector exactly.
But now I find it, THX AGAIN! :) Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check digit buttons tag property (UIButton settings in the Interface Builder). It looks like all of them has value **0**. Just set tags for buttons propiretly (ex. tag=3 for button with digit 3).

Comment: Thank you! I read in the book that I have to set the tags for buttons, but I can't find where in Inspector exactly.